# Что представляют собой файлы *.sql?

Tags: mysql, php, sql

Привет.

Меня интересует, что это за файлы. Как их подключать к серверу PHP? Используют ли эти файлы для выполнения запросов к БД?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это обычно текстовые файлы, которые хранят SQL запросы. Соответственно, с использованием соответствующих инструментов (например phpmyAdmin или консольных утилит) их можно "выполнить".

А вот что будет результатом - неизвестно, нужно смотреть внутрь. Либо будет добавлено много новых записей, либо все удалено, либо даже структура базы изменена.

Как использовать в php, можно посмотреть на [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4027769/running-mysql-sql-files-in-php).

Обычно такие файлы поставляют с различными скриптами, что бы сделать предварительную подготовку базы (создать таблицы, наполнить данными).

Comment: Тоесть логика такова:получаем содержимое файлы.Отделяем очередной запрос от других и выполняем запрос?А зачем их хранить в файлах єти все запросы?Это дает большую гибкость?

Comment: потому что можно в консоли написать

    mysql -u username -p -h localhost DATA-BASE-NAME < data.sql

(конечно, прописав свои `username`, `DATA-BASE-NAME` и `data.sql` и импортировать это все одним махом.